# Is there a platform-independent way to programmatically remove a file from a zip / jar?

Tags: java, io, zip

Hopefully without having to unpack and repack the archive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Use [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net/).

> TrueZIP is a Java based virtual file system (VFS) which enables client applications to perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations on archive files as if they were virtual directories, even with nested archive files in multithreaded environments.

It takes a little bit of work to fully grok the API, but once you do, you'll see how fantastically easy it is to use for all sorts of tasks involving compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Zip File System Provider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) in JDK7 which allows you to treat a zip file as a file system, which means that you can perform operations, such as moving, copying, deleting, renaming etc, just as you would with ordinary files.

Also see this article, [Java 7: Working with Zip Files](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/java-7-working-with-zip-files.html), which explains, in a bit more detail, how you can create a zip file system and perform various operations on it.

Comment: The code in that blogpost is buggy, for example the create method doesn't include empty directories. I tried using the `Zip File System Provider` but found it difficult to access the files within the custom filesystem in the case where I have a zip archive in the same directory as a folder with the same name (for example \folder and \folder.zip) because I couldn't figure out how to treat the filesystem like a directory. Using `filesystem.getPath(path)` returns a relative path to the root of that filesystem... so I'm not too sure how to use it even after reading through all the docs.